# Can't pip install egenix-mx-base

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an exe from using pyinstaller with

- python 3.8
- windows 7
- pip 20.1.1

`78935 WARNING: Hidden import "mx.DateTime" not found!`

I tried:

`pip install  egenix-mx-base`

However I get this error:

```
  Using cached egenix-mx-base-3.2.9.zip (74 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe'
-c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppDat
a\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5lbz35_k\\egenix-mx-base\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"
'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5lbz35_k\\egenix-mx-base\\
setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().
replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'
"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg
-info-l5hzmpcw'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5lbz35_k\egenix-mx-ba
se\
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5lbz35_k\egenix-mx-base
\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        import mxSetup, os
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5lbz35_k\egenix-mx-base
\mxSetup.py", line 229
        print 'running mxSetup.py with setuptools patched distutils'
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('run
ning mxSetup.py with setuptools patched distutils')?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check th
e logs for full command output.
```

I tried all the solutions form this issue but nothing works:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`egenix-mx-base` is for Python2 only. For date/time manipulation there are enough other modules including modules from the stdlib: [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), `calendar`, `time`.